# i can't run bash script in other script

Tags: bash

This is my script in bash which I added to user crontab, and the command `bash /home/lobby/start.sh` doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

```
#!/bin/bash
if ps aux | grep lobby | grep "Ss" | grep "SCREEN"; then
        pkill -f lobby
        screen -wipe
        if bash /home/lobby/start.sh; then
                echo "$(date '+%y-%m-%d') Serwer dzialal Uruchomiono pomyslnie" >> /home/logi-serwery/logi-autorestart-lobby.txt
                bash /home/lobby/start.sh;
        else
                echo "$(date '+%y-%m-%d') Serwer dzialal blad podczas uruchamiania" >> /home/logi-serwery/logi-autorestart-lobby.txt

        fi
else
        if bash /home/lobby/start.sh; then
                echo "$(date '+%y-%m-%d') Serwer nie dzialal uruchomilem" >> /home/logi-serwery/logi-autorestart-lobby.txt
                bash /home/lobby/start.sh;

        else
                echo "$(date '+%y-%m-%d') Serwer nie dzialal blad podczas uruchomienia" >> /home/logi-serwery/logi-autorestart-lobby.txt

        fi
fi
```

Comment: Does the line `bash /home/lobby/start.sh/silnik.jar` work properly if you execute it separately in your shell?

Comment: yes, it work when i go cd /home/lobby and execute bash start.sh sorry not /home/lobby/start.sh/silnik.jar my mistake

Comment: The same result if you execute your script inside your script with `./` instead of `bash`?

Comment: yes, in start.sh i have only screen -dmS sky java -Xms1G -Xmx3G jar silnik.jar nogui

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Error messages?  Is the script you are running assuming any environment variables are set?  Is it assuming a current directory?  Those are the most common issues with things "not working" in cron.

Comment: no error messages, when I try to bash script (up) i have only the result - command from bash file which i want to start ( bash /home/lobby/start.sh ) The result is the output of /home/lobby/start.sh file

Comment: I'm not quite clear, what output do you fail to get?  You might try running with `xtrace` turned on, using `set -x` at the start of your script (output goes to `stderr`).

Comment: should i try `bash -x /home/lobby/start.sh` ??

Comment: I get this output: `mcgo      6043  0.0  0.0  27132  2620 ?        Ss   10:31   0:00 SCREEN -dmS lobby java -Xmx2G -jar silnik.jar
`

Comment: You'll need to change directory to the place you're storing `silnik.jar` in order for that to work. Alternatively, you could provide the full path to `silnik.jar` rather than using a relative one. (Perhaps `/home/lobby/silnik.jar`?)